# SSIS Flat File Destination Settings Not Saving (Revert Back to original)

Tags: ssis, flatfiledestination

Description: When reopening a flat file destination the settings revert back to the default settings.

Application: SSIS

Area of Application: File Destination Editor

Steps Performed:
1. Double click Flat File Destination
2. Click update
3. Update Columns,  Advanced Settings
4. Click OK
5. Click Update and the setting are not saved and revert back to the original values.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYnQc.png)